# How do we celebrate Tu B'Av?

Tags: minhag, mitzvah, chagim-holidays, 15th-of-av

Besides the dancing maidens of Jerusalem, [many other significant events](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/717167/jewish/Why-Do-We-Celebrate-the-15th-of-Av.htm) occurred on Tu B'Av for it to be considered one of the holiest days of the year. As mentioned in a [previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/how-was-tu-bav-observed-as-a-matchmaking-singles-meeting-event-through-histor), many institutions host singles meetings on Tu B'Av.

Aside from matchmaking, is there any precedence for other ways of celebrating the holiday, such as a particular study program or engaging in particular mitzvot? What do married people do?

Comment: [Or HaChaim Siman 131/6][1]  - Tachnun is omitted on Tu B'Av

  [1]: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=24

Comment: Yeah, I was looking more for the "doing" part of the day, rather than the "omitting."

Comment: that's why i put it in the comment section instead of an answer ;)

Comment: Rashi on Taanis 31a implies that from the 15th and onwards you should increase your nightly Torah study.